# get closest small value in array compare to given number or get the last value

Tags: javascript, object

if I have an object

```
const times={
  sunrise:"5:32",
  sunset:"6:22",
  midnight:"12:11"
}
```

and I have `time = 6:10`

and I want the output is `sunrise:"5:32"`

and if `time = 3:16` smaller than any value then the value will be last one of object   `midnight:"12:11"`

Comment: Your title mentions an array, but the question is about an object. Which is it? If order is important, you should generally use an array.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so we can help you with it, we're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each time to seconds for comparison.

```js
const times={
  sunrise:"5:32",
  sunset:"6:22",
  midnight:"12:11"
};
function getLower(times, time) {
  function toSecs(str) {
    const [hours, seconds] = str.split(':').map(Number);
    return hours * 60 + seconds;
  }
  const target = toSecs(time), entries = Object.entries(times)
                      .sort((a, b) => toSecs(a[1]) - toSecs(b[1]));
  // the sorting can be removed if the object properties are always in ascending order of time
  return entries.find(([k, v]) => toSecs(v) < target) ?? entries.at(-1);
}
console.log(getLower(times, '6:10'));
console.log(getLower(times, '3:16'));
```